# Symfony2 kernel->getRootDir() returns a different value between environments

Tags: php, symfony, debian

In a Symfony2 application, I use **SwiftMailer** to send mails with the manual command :

`php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send`

In each mail, an image is embedded from a custom mailer service like this :

`$this->mailer->addEmbed('embed_logo', $this->kernel->getRootDir().'/../web/bundles/mybundle/images/my-logo.png');`

In the "dev" environment, `$this->kernel->getRootDir()` returns the good value (`/var/www/mydirectory/sources/mysymfoproject/app`), so the command works. But in the **"prod"** environment, `$this->kernel->getRootDir()` returns a bad value `(/var/www/sources/mysymfoproject/app`) while the parent directory **"mydirectory"** is very present in the file system...

The displayed error in the terminal is :

**Unable to open file for reading [/var/www/sources/mysymfoproject/app/../web/bundles/mybundle/images/my-logo.png]**

Please, any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you use the same `AppKernel` for both dev and prod environments?

Comment: Yes the same, app/AppKernel.php with 'prod'/false and 'dev'/true parameters in app.php and app_dev.php (the rest of the features is ok, it's only the spool send that doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, since the getRootDir function is nothing more than:

```
$r = new \ReflectionObject($this);
$this->rootDir = dirname($r->getFileName());
```

Is the production environment deployed somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, the production environment isn't in the same machine. Do you think the cause is the Debian configuration ?. In the getRootDir

Comment: In the getRootDir, i have `$r = new \ReflectionObject($this); $this->rootDir = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($r->getFileName()));`

Comment: Which Symfony version are you running?

Comment: Symfony 2.5 and PHP 5.5

Comment: Hmm, I think it has something to do with the configuration of your server since it's both exactly the same code that's running.

Comment: Ok, I'll check my server configuration and continue my tests. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

In the *app/mailspool/default* repository, there was a hidden file (representing a mail waiting) and this file probably results from an older version of the application hosted on another server. Hence, the directory tree was different.

So I removed this file and everything is ok !

Thanks :)